# Why is the form ignoring submit?

Tags: html, forms

I made a begining of a question submit page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Question</title>
 </head>
<body>
<from action="contformer.php" method="post">
<input name="mail" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Please enter your email, so we can contact you back."><br>
<input type="text" name="sub" placeholder="Enter the subject here"><br>
<input type="text" name="q" size="50"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit your question">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why it does nothing when i click the "Submit your question" button?

Comment: Can you please post the code that is supposed to handle the request? Does the request get submitted to the Webserver?

Comment: No, my problem was that it didnt try to send it

Answer (score 1):

You have an syntax error 
There should be form and not from action

Answer (score 0):

Please change `<**from** action="contformer.php" method="post">` to **form**